# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping'

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I created a web application using Spring 4.3.1.Two days ago the application was working perfectly fine but now I am getting following errors.I am unable to make out actual cause of problem.

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring-dispatcher        threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.OnlineStore.DAO.UserDetailsDAOImpl] for bean with name 'userDetailsImpl' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.OnlineStore.DAO.UserDetailsDAOImpl
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.OnlineStore.DAO.UserDetailsDAOImpl] for bean with name 'userDetailsImpl' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.OnlineStore.DAO.UserDetailsDAOImpl
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.OnlineStore.DAO.UserDetailsDAOImpl] for bean with name 'userDetailsImpl' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.OnlineStore.DAO.UserDetailsDAOImpl
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1357)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1450)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:446)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:424)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:410)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:75)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:58)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:120)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:76)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:74)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:121)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:97)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.OnlineStore.DAO.UserDetailsDAOImpl
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1891)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1734)
    org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:394)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1402)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1450)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:446)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:424)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:410)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:75)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:58)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:120)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:76)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:74)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:121)
    org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:97)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd">

<!--
<bean id = "HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>

 <bean name ="/welcome.html" class="retailbeans.HomeClass">
</bean> -->

<context:component-scan base-package="com.OnlineStore.Control"/>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix"><value>/WEB-INF/Pages/</value></property>
<property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>

</bean>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />


<!-- Initialization for data source -->
   <bean id="storedatasource" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYSQL" />
   <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
   <property name="username" value="abhi" />
   <property name="password" value="abhi123" />
   </bean>

<!--  Dao class configuration in spring -->
 <bean id="userDetailsImpl" class="com.OnlineStore.DAO.UserDetailsDAOImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="storedatasource"/>
 </bean>



</beans>
```

UserDetailsDAOImpl.java

```
package com.OnlineStore.DAO;




import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import com.OnlineStore.DAO.IUserDetailsDAO;
import com.OnlineStore.Entity.CategoryEntity;
import com.OnlineStore.Entity.ProductDetailEntity;
import com.OnlineStore.Entity.UserDetailEntity;
import com.OnlineStore.Entity.UserDetailsEntity;


public class UserDetailsDAOImpl implements IUserDetailsDAO{
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private List<ProductDetailEntity> productListMen=new ArrayList<ProductDetailEntity>();
    private List<ProductDetailEntity> productListWomen=new ArrayList<ProductDetailEntity>();
    private List<ProductDetailEntity> productListChild=new ArrayList<ProductDetailEntity>();
    private List<ProductDetailEntity> productListMenDisc=new ArrayList<ProductDetailEntity>();
    private List<ProductDetailEntity> productListWomenDisc=new ArrayList<ProductDetailEntity>();
    private List<ProductDetailEntity> productListChildDisc=new ArrayList<ProductDetailEntity>();
    private boolean flagPopulation=false;

     public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
          this.dataSource = dataSource;
       }





    @Override
    public UserDetailEntity validateUser(UserDetailEntity user) {
String sql = "SELECT * FROM userdetails where enPassword =? and  email =?";

        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, user.getPassword());
            ps.setString(2, user.getEmail());
            ResultSet result=ps.executeQuery();
            UserDetailEntity userdetails=new UserDetailEntity();
            if(result != null && result.next()){
                userdetails.setFirstname(result.getString("firstName"));
                userdetails.setLastname(result.getString("lastName"));
                userdetails.setEmail(result.getString("email"));
                userdetails.setPhone(result.getString("mobile"));
                userdetails.setFirstname(result.getString("firstName"));
                }
            ps.close();
            return userdetails;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {}
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void addUser(UserDetailEntity user) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO userdetails " +
                "(enPassword, firstName , lastName, email , mobile, gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? ,? ,? )";

        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, user.getPassword());
            ps.setString(2, user.getFirstname());
            ps.setString(3, user.getLastname());
            ps.setString(4, user.getEmail());
            ps.setString(5, user.getPhone());
            ps.setString(6,user.getGender());

            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {}
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public List<ProductDetailEntity> productDetailsList() {

        String sql = "select * from ProductDetail" ;

        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ProductDetailEntity productModel=null; 
            ResultSet result=ps.executeQuery();
            List<ProductDetailEntity> productList=new ArrayList<ProductDetailEntity>();
            if(result != null){
                while (result.next()){
                    productModel=new ProductDetailEntity();
                    productModel.setProductName(result.getString("name"));
                    productModel.setBrand(result.getString("brand"));
                    productModel.setDescription(result.getString("description"));
                    productModel.setModelnumber(result.getString("modelnumber"));
                    productModel.setDialcolour(result.getString("dialcolour"));
                    productModel.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(result.getString("price")));
                    productModel.setStrap(result.getString("strap"));
                    productModel.setDiameter(result.getString("casediameter"));
                    productModel.setWaterResistant(result.getString("waterresistant"));
                    productModel.setDiscount(result.getString("discount"));
                    productModel.setGender(result.getString("gender"));

                    String imageUrl=result.getString("imageURL");
                    ArrayList <String> images=new ArrayList<String>();
                    StringTokenizer strToken=new StringTokenizer(imageUrl, ",");
                    while(strToken.hasMoreTokens()){
                        images.add(strToken.nextToken());
                    }

                    productModel.setImage(images);
                    productModel.setMainImage(images.get(0));

                    if(result.getString("discount") != "0%"){
                        String discount=productModel.getDiscount();
                         Integer discountNumber=Integer.parseInt(discount.substring(0,discount.indexOf("%")));
                        double discountedPercentage = discountNumber/100.0;
                        double discountedPrice=productModel.getPrice() - (productModel.getPrice()*discountedPercentage);

                        System.out.println(discountedPrice);
                        productModel.setDiscountedPrice(discountedPrice);
                    }else{
                        productModel.setDiscountedPrice(productModel.getPrice());
                    }

                System.out.println(productModel.getProductName());
                productList.add(productModel);
                if(!flagPopulation)
                if(result.getString("gender").equalsIgnoreCase("Male")){
                productListMen.add(productModel);
                if(!result.getString("discount").equals("0%"))
                productListMenDisc.add(productModel);
                }
                else if(result.getString("gender").equalsIgnoreCase("Female")){
                    productListWomen.add(productModel);
                    if(!result.getString("discount").equals("0%"))
                        productListWomenDisc.add(productModel);
                }
                else{
                    productListChild.add(productModel);
                    if(!result.getString("discount").equals("0%"))
                        productListChildDisc.add(productModel);
                }

                }
            }

            flagPopulation=true;
            ps.close();
            return productList;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {}
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProductDetailEntity> productDetailsListMen() {
        return productListMen;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProductDetailEntity> productDetailsListWomen() {
        return productListWomen;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProductDetailEntity> productDetailsListChild() {
        return productListChild;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProductDetailEntity> productDetailsListMenDiscount() {
        return productListMenDisc;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProductDetailEntity> productDetailsListWomenDiscount() {
        return productListWomenDisc;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProductDetailEntity> productDetailsListChildDiscount() {
        return productListChildDisc;
    }
     @Override
      public void addProduct(ProductDetailEntity product) {
       String sql = "INSERT INTO ProductDetail " +
         "( name, brand, description , modelnumber, dialcolour , strap , casediameter ,"
         + "waterresistant , price , discount,gender,imageURL) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,?,?,?)";

       Connection conn = null;

       try {
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, product.getProductName());
        ps.setString(2, product.getBrand());
        ps.setString(3, product.getDescription());
        ps.setString(4, product.getModelnumber());
        ps.setString(5, product.getDialcolour());
        ps.setString(6,product.getStrap());
        ps.setString(7, product.getDiameter());
        ps.setString(8,product.getWaterResistant());
        ps.setDouble(9, Double.parseDouble(product.getPricetext()));
        ps.setString(10,product.getDiscount()+"%");
        ps.setString(11,product.getGender());
        ps.setString(12,product.getMainImage());

        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();

       } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

       } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
         try {
          conn.close();
         } catch (SQLException e) {}
        }
       }

      }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for UserDetailsDAOImpl ?

Comment: @IamNguele Plz check UserDetailsDAOImpl

Comment: I would try to clean, rebuild and redeploy the project

Comment: Thanx @RC.Found the solution.Jars were missing

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.
I rechecked all the jars and found following 2 jars missing.
commons-logging-1.2.jar
commons-logging-1.2-javadoc.jar